# Bitmap's bounds in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap, surfaceview

My question is: a bitmap had to be square or is possible delete the invisible parts around the colored image? I have a bitmap in a SurfaceView with an hand in the center and i want calculate the bounds of this hand deleting the invisible around it, cause i have problems with the onClick Method. Without calculate every X and Y, is possible know the bounds of the hand with a Method or other things? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first question: any bitmap that retains some level of transparency has to have an alpha channel so in your case a hand has an alpha channel thus you cannot just delete those alpha pixels, because if you do the transparent part will remain black. You will have to use either ARGB_4444 format or ARGB_8888 format to retain this alpha channel. As far as getting the bitmaps bounds, use a Rect or some bounding shape maybe an oval, to accurately know if your finger is touching it, you can't just know exactly if your touch is within the bounds of this hand because this hand image, at certain portions contain different widths, and heights, however you can test if your touch is touching your hand exactly by using pixel perfect collision. Here is how it works:

```
class drawingView extends View {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Bitmap bitmap = yourHand;

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x, y, null);
        rect.set(x, y, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        invalidate();
    }

    public void onClick() {
        if(rect.contains(event.getX(), event.getY(), && bitmap.getPixel(event.getX() - rect.left, event.getY() - rect.top) != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
          // you know you exactly touched the hand even out of the transparent region
    }
}
```

I started you off I'm sure you will understand what's going on here.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do would be to **take the picture of the hand and crop it** down to the size of the hand.

This way, you'll have a smaller file and won't have to implement some kind of code work around.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use a png file with the right transparency in place, which means the part around the hand should have the transparency .

Now for retaining the transparency of the image when using the BitmapFactory,make sure that your image is pulled in as ARGB_8888

Comment: Wut. I think you're going to need to clarify.